# Why does Spyder say "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'"?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run some selenium code in Spyder but I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Any ideas as to why this may be?.

Comment: Did you install Selenium?

Comment: If you are working with an external module, you must check to make sure you have installed it

Comment: I installed Selenium via command prompt. Do I need to do something in addition to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install Anaconda.
2. Open 'Anaconda Prompt' as administrator.
3. Type the following:

   conda install -c conda-forge selenium